# Counting number of pallindromic substring

Tags: dynamic-programming

Computing the number of pallindromic substrings.

I have generated all the possible combinations and checking if its palindrome, the count variable is storing the actual count.

```py
def pallindromic(str):
    temp=[[0]*len(str) for _ in range(len(str))]
    count=0
    for i in range(len(str)):
        for j in range(i,len(str)+1):
            a=str[i:j]
            count=count+1 if a==a[::-1] else count


    #print(count)
    return count

print(pallindromic("MADAM"))
```

For madam the total should be 7, I am getting 12, not sure how is count getting increment on every loop

Answer (score 1):

During the first iteration of your `j` loop, `j` has the same value of `i`, so that `str[i:j]` is the empty string, which passes the test and increments `count`.

You want to avoid testing empty strings.  For example, you can change the `j` loop:

```
        for j in range(i+1, len(str)+1):
```